# Cutom Font in css using font face

Tags: html, css

I have uploaded the font MTCORSVA.TTF on server and can be accessible with source url too. 
But When I implement it using @font-face , it doesnt show up on site.

What am i lacking here?

```css
.bottomtext{
 font-family: "MTCORSVA";
 color:    red;
}





/*fonts*/
@font-face {
font-family: "MTCORSVA";
src: url("azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/css/fonts/MTCORSVA.TTF") format("TTF");
}
```

```html
<div class=" bottom_header">
<div class="bottom_header1"><span class="bottomtext">Love Column</span>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move your TTF file to in your Fonts folder.

```
src: url("azlily.bex.jp/eccube_1/html/template/default/css/fonts/MTCORSVA.TTF") format("TTF");
```

change above code to

```
src: url("../fonts/MTCORSVA.TTF");
```